# Getting System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added while using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, quartz.net, system.text.json

I was trying to get a value from a json object during **crawling** data into SQL Server using **System.Text.json**. The json data's structure is like this:

```
skus:
1v9beswiav1wo91j:{...,...}
```

The key `1v9beswiav1wo91j` is unreachabe to me, so I use `JsonNode skus = item["skus"].AsObject().ElementAtOrDefault(0).Value;` to get its first value and do some parsing works.

However, It was ok during first thousands of circles. But it throws  `System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 0rdfs1976wzsx8lj (Parameter 'propertyName')` soon. **And the Key `0rdfs1976wzsx8lj` is exactly the key above**.
The whole error text:

```
 System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 0rdfs1976wzsx8lj (Parameter 'propertyName')
         at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException_DuplicateKey(String paramName, String propertyName)
         at System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject.InitializeIfRequired()
         at System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject.GetEnumerator()
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetElement[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 index, TSource& element)
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 index)
         at BlazorApp1.Server.Jobs.HFJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) in D:\repos\BlazorApp1\Server\Jobs\HFJob.cs:line 67
```

And the function I used:

```
while (true)
            {
                using HttpClient client = new(new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookies }) { BaseAddress = baseUri };
                var post = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                JsonNode jsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(await post.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                JsonArray jsonArray = jsonNode["results"].AsArray();
                if (jsonArray.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in jsonArray)
                    {
                        JsonNode skus = item["skus"].AsObject().ElementAtOrDefault(0).Value;
                        Product product = new()
                        {
                            parsing work;
                        };
                        Product product1 = await _context.Products.FindAsync(keyValues: product.Id);
                        if (product1 != null)
                        {
                            update entity;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await _context.Products.AddAsync(product);
                            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I guess the main reason may be repeatly getting json objects into stack, and two json object with same Key conflicts.

**But I wasn't using any array or hash set structure to restore the objects**, these json objects should be destroyed after parsing, **how can a newly created object conflicts with a destroyed one?**

By the way, **theoretically there shouldn't be two json objects with same Key, for every data I crawled relying on it to identify.**

I suspect that **there may be a concurrent problem too which wrongly request same data twice at two different life circles**. I used Quartz.net to host this service.
Please help me, I can't figure out how to resolve this question.

Json data details

```
skus:{
  "5c5cnedd7mo7m9qf": {
    "allowBargain": false,
    "bigPackAmount": 1,
    "buyAmount": 1,
    "canSell": true,
    "count": 0,
    "extendCode": "",
    "hasStock": false,
    "innerSellCtrlTags": "",
    "lastAmount": 0,
    "limitBuyAmount": 2147483647,
    "middlePackAmount": 1,
    "minAmount": 1,
    "minOrder": 1,
    "modCount": 1,
    "oldPrice": 0,
    "orgOldPrice": -1,
    "orgPrice": -1,
    "packAmount": 1,
    "packDesc": "",
    "packUnits": "",
    "photo": null,
    "price": 99999,
    "priceEndDiff": "",
    "priceEndTime": "",
    "priceOfOrg": null,
    "priceTip": "",
    "priceType": "",
    "sellCtrlTags": "(041)",
    "sellStateTip": "",
    "skuCode": "22459",
    "skuId": "5c5cnedd7mo7m9qf",
    "specDesc": "",
    "specValueDef": "",
    "specialPrice": -1,
    "stepPriceDesc": "",
    "stockTag": {
      "amount": 0,
      "stockState": "",
      "stockType": ""
    },
    "tokenPrice": 0,
    "units": "",
    "weight": 0
  }
}
```

I tried to destroy the json object at the end of one circle but I can't find a way to manually dispose it and auto GC takes over the whole life of the app. And the concurrent problem is hard to track and ensure its fault.

Comment: Can you show some of the actual json?

Comment: I can't edit the question right now. I put part of it here : ` skus: 3drtmwvuan5p42br: {allowBargain: false, bigPackAmount: 0, buyAmount: 1, canSell: true, count: 0, extendCode: "", hasStock: true, innerSellCtrlTags: "", lastAmount: 0, limitBuyAmount: 2147483647, middlePackAmount: 0, minAmount: 1}`

Comment: Already put on the actual json

Comment: Do `parsing work` and `update entity` do anything with `jsonArray` or `skus`? Concurrency should not be an issue here because you're only dealing with local variables (though they are technically fields captured in a closure, this should be invisible), but modifying things you're iterating over is still a possibility. Of course, a simpler explanation is that your JSON is not what you think it should be -- notably, you have only posted an excerpt, which is itself not valid JSON. The *full* JSON is an array, according to your source.

Comment: No, parsing work is just use data in json object to construct a new object with type product without operating json object and update Entity is just a simple `_context.update(product)`, and the bug throws exactly at `JsonNode skus = item["skus"].AsObject().ElementAtOrDefault(0).Value;`. So, the problem lays behind reading json object in.

Comment: I turned to NewtonSoft.Json later. I didn't change anything, just using NewtonSoft.Json way to rewrite the program, and it haven't thrown bug yet. So, the System.Text.Json is the one to blame. A built-in lib behaves worse than third-party lib at simple work. Wow, good work , Microsoft!

Comment: By switching to Json.NET you may be hiding the problem rather than solving it.  If you parse JSON with duplicate property names using `JToken.Parse()`, e.g. `JToken.Parse("""{"1v9beswiav1wo91j":"a","1v9beswiav1wo91j":"b"}""")`, then the second value will silently replace the first.  To get an error you need to parse with `JsonLoadSettings.DuplicatePropertyNameHandling=DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.Error`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/f3rz7o.